# DomPDF Failed To Generate PDF from Simple HTML Bootstrap

Tags: php, dompdf

I have this simple HTML file (`simple.html`) to test DomPDF :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here's my DomPDF generator file :

```
<?php
require_once '../../../lib/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$invoice = file_get_contents('invoice.html');
$dompdf->loadHtml($invoice);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

?>
```

and here's the error message...

```
Warning: fopen(/home/***/lib/dompdf/lib/fonts/345658495770f44fa67e0e37c1b01eb4.ufm): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/***/lib/dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/src/FontLib/AdobeFontMetrics.php on line 45

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/***/lib/dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/src/FontLib/AdobeFontMetrics.php on line 191
```

why the PHP failed to open /lib/dompdf/lib/fonts folder? it already have `drwxrwxr-x` permission.

and why I don't see any `345658495770f44fa67e0e37c1b01eb4.ufm` file there?

thank you

Comment: Is this a fresh install of dompdf or did you copy from one server to another? It's possible the values in dompdf_font_family_cache.php are no longer accurate. I'd try resetting the font directory to the default.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried by saving all the needed html in a variable *$html* and then using

```
$dompdf->loadHtml(html_entity_decode($html));
```

It should work when taking html from an external file, too. Try replacing your line

```
$dompdf->loadHtml($invoice);
```

with

```
$dompdf->loadHtml(html_entity_decode($invoice));
```