# laravel-dompdf return error,code not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dompdf

I have this code to try to generate a report as pdf:

```
$details=array(
    'id'=>$find->id,
    'full_letter_title'=>$find->full_letter_title,
    'smarok_no'=>$find->smarok_no
);
$data['details']=$details;


$pdf = PDF::loadView('letter.view', $data);
return $pdf->stream();
```

But it return error

```
ErrorException in Adobe_Font_Metrics.php line 42: fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\ams\storage\fonts/ba50cf37c0b6d75f8275d2b44106f606.ufm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I cant understand whats wrong here.

Comment: give a proper file folder path to generate a pdf.

Comment: I wrote this but not work @Kaushalshah $pdf = PDF::loadView('app/resources/views/letter/view.blade.php', $data);

Comment: i think this link may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606120/dompdf-failed-to-generate-pdf-from-simple-html-bootstrap

Comment: I had this before. I solved it by creating fonts directory

Answer (score 1):

**STEPS**

1. crate "fonts" Folder inside storage
2. create file "5ab413ede0c0d14abbb48febee3bfdfb.ufm" or other "File Name" Which show in error inside "fonts" Folder
3. Giving Permission "fonts" Folder

**NOW IT'S RUN**

[reference] (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/269)

Answer (score 0):

This will be solved by creating Font Directory inside the Storage folder. This is used to store the temporary files . But anyhow Dompdf is not a effective library for PDF . I already used this and gotta more css issues about alignments . I would suggest you to use the Phanthomjs PDF . https://github.com/danielboendergaard/phantom-pdf It's much better than DomPDF .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('letter.view', $data)->setOptions(['defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);
```

It worked for me, i didn't create any font folder/file